# How to optimize method with nested if condition

Tags: c#, linq

Hello I want to optimize this method with many nested `if else` with performance side or structure side also.

Here I have many condition for every case I did a query to my datasource this is the principle.

The above method works, but I would like to know if there is any way to make it more readable and less of a performance cost?

Here is my code :

```
if ((inCheckbox != null) && (inCheckbox == "true"))
{
    if ((inCheckboxQu != null) && (inCheckboxQu == "true"))
    {
        if (wordArraySplit.Length > 1)
        {
            var request = from qu in dataInitial
                        from p in q.Pannea
                        where wordArraySplit.All(word => p.Title.Contains(word))
                        select q;

            dataResult = dataResult.Union(request);
        }
        else
        {
            var valueArray = wordArraySplit[0];
            var query = dataInitial.Where(qu=> qu.Pannea.Any(p => p.Title.Contains(valueArray)));
            dataResult = dataResult.Union(query);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (wordArraySplit.Length > 1)
        {
            dataResult = from qu in dataInitial
                         from p in qu.Pannea
                         where wordArraySplit.All(word => p.Title.Contains(word))
                         select q;
        }
        else
        {
            var valueArray = wordArraySplit[0];
            dataResult = dataInitial.Where(qu=> qu.Pannea.Any(p => p.Title.Contains(valueArray)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just eye-balling both sides of  the `if (motsClesInclureSplit.Length > 1)` if-else section. Wouldn't the Linq query on the "if" side give the same results as the "else" side when `motsClesInclureSplit.Length == 1`?

Comment: @DanielDearlove  yes but the difference in side == 1 i'am using Union(query) that is the difference

Comment: The answer of @JonasH and I are in agreement. When you say "optimize this method" and "less of a performance cost", what do you mean? Do you mean "make this callback more readable"? Do you mean "execute the Linq query in the minimum time"? Can you be more specific, please.

Comment: @DanielDearlove When I said performance I'm talking for all the line of code so for conditions and also the query everthing that can speed up the traitement

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Your method looks like a callback which could be called many times before you actually enumerate the subset of objects from `dataResultInitial`. Multiple callbacks results in many calls to [`Enumerable.Union()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-5.0). Your callback just builds the query that gets increasingly complex which will result in a sequence of Linq queries when you finally call `ToList()`. If you can remove the recursive calls to `dataResultInitial` then the Linq query will execute more quickly.

Comment: @DanielDearlove my method will be called once not many times I don't have a foreach loop in my code and how i remove dataResultInitial  because i have cases of using it and it is not the same scenario

Comment: Thank you for providing some more context @mecab95. If you can create a benchmark (possibly using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org)) then we could see this in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). From there, we can duplicate your exact problem on our own PC's and we can give specific advice that you can test on your own machine. Otherwise, it is hard to give good advice with a lot of missing context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue you are focused on the wrong thing. While branches can be fairly slow as instructions goes, it is still measured in clock-cycles. In comparison I would expect the linq-statements to have far more performance impact than the nested if-statements.

Performance and readability can often be conflicting requirements. While improving both is nice when it is possible, eventually you are often forced to chose one or the other. Notably, Linq has some decent overhead, so if performance is important, regular loops are often better.

Some specific comments:

1. `(inCheckbox != null) && (inCheckbox == "true")` you should be able to just write `inCheckbox == "true"` since `null != "true"`. But why are you using string comparisons instead of booleans in the first place?
2. I do not think you *need* special handling of the `wordArraySplit.Length <= 1` case. It may make some small performance difference, but probably not much. Measure if you are unsure.
3. The queries look the same to me, except the union part after the query, so you should be able to move the query code into a separate method to avoid repeating yourself.

And if you are concerned about performance, start by measuring and profiling the code to see if you have a problem in the first place, and if there is a problem, where it is. My guess is that code like that would be very fast, unless the lists are huge, or some database access is involved.

Comment: Why I don't need special handling of the wordArraySplit.Length <= 1 ? because when I test the query sql between  (from q in dtResultInitial
                                        from p in q.Proposition .....) and  dtResultInitial.Where(q => q.Proposition.Any(p => p.Libelle.Contains(valueArray))) I don't have the same results

Comment: @mecab95 Is that intentional? Just looking at the code the different branches look like they are meant to do the same thing. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance with this type of checks what you usually do is use the checks that fail most often first for example

`if test1 and test2: ...`

then `test1` should be the one most often failing so you dont have to evaluate `test2`

To make it more redable I usually compine the tests in a different function and return true or false and keep the logic in the main function like this :

```
if functiontest():
  #do_something

def functiontest():
  if test1 and test2 and test3 and test3:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

In your case you need two of this function since you basically have 4 final stages.

***dummy code is in python style***

Also look at this for another idea they suggest making a dictionary with possible combinations: [readable nested if statements](http://also%20look%20at%20this%20for%20another%20idea%20they%20suggest%20making%20a%20dictionary%20with%20possible%20combinations:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927718/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-nested-if-statements-in-python)

Comment: Here in my method I don't have an idea what is the one most often failing , because u can have everytime a scenario done by the user of the interface web

Comment: if you cannot guess what might be more often then you dont have any information to use to optimize the checks performance wise. You can still make it more readable though as I suggested.

Comment: also look at this for another idea they suggest making a dictionary with possible combinations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927718/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-nested-if-statements-in-python

Comment: Just for information in my exemple inCheckbox check in the first line, it is the condition that is most often to fail , so i'am working already with your principle.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
if ((inCheckbox == null) || (inCheckbox != "true"))
    return;

if (wordArraySplit.Length > 1)
{
    dataResult = from qu in dataResultInitial
    from p in qu.Pannea
    where wordArraySplit.All(word => p.Title.Contains(word))
    select q;
    
    if ((inCheckboxQu != null) && (inCheckboxQu == "true"))
        dataResult = dataResult.Union(request);

}
else
{
    var valueArray = wordArraySplit[0];
    var query = dataResultIni.Where(qu=> qu.Pannea.Any(p => p.Title.Contains(valueArray)));
    if ((inCheckboxQu != null) && (inCheckboxQu == "true"))
        dataResult = dataResult.Union(query);
}
```

i don't know if the `return` fits the rest of your function.

Comment: I want to know if this code speed up the performance or just more readable ?

Comment: The different speed of the if statements would be minimal in your case. But I find the code is much better to read this way

Comment: The performance differences that would be achieved by changing the if statements would not be noticeable. But maybe you can save performance on the rest of the function

Comment: "Speed up the performance" could mean 2 things in this context. Do you mean the performance of the callback? Do you mean the performance of the query/queries when you enumerate the objects?